# wordpress domain setup with ec2 apache

Tags: dns

I'm struggling to get my WP domains to display correctly. I'm using ec2 apache with a domain from namecheap.

In namecheap, I've done the "pointing," putting my elastic IP for both the @ and www, and selected "A (Address) for both.

Right now, www.mysite.com directs to the homepage of my WP. But as soon as I click links in my WP, the url goes back to xxx.ElasticIP.xx/sub-page instead of www.mysite.com/sub-page

The General settings in my WP still have the xxx.elasticIP.xx for both the site URL and WP URL.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: "The General settings in my WP still have the xxx.elasticIP.xx for both the site URL and WP URL." aaaand you can't figure out that that's what needs to change?

Comment: Hmm thought that that had broken the page earlier when I tried, but that was indeed the simple fix.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All the links in a wordpress database are relational, and based on the URL structure that was used when the database was created. What you need to do is [follow the steps to change the URL of the Wordpress instance](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) and that should resolve your problem.

This is common when changing from a dev platform to a live site. FWIW I think that manually changing it in the database it the easiest way to accomplish what you're looking to do.

Comment: Turned out the answer was even simpler, but this was helpful, thanks!